# Using one variable from a console in a windows form

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have this project:

[image]

And I need to use a variable that is in the "TransactionHandler.cs" in the "Enviar Faturas.cs" the TransactioHandler is a class library and the Enviar Faturas is a Windows Form.
Is it possible to do what I want? If so how should I do it?

UPDATE:

I have this variable declares in TransactionHandler.cs

`var numfatura = _transaction.TransDocument + _transaction.TransSerial + _transaction.TransDocNumber;`

And I need to use it on the Windows Form "Enviar Faturas".

UPDATE 2:

I have this code to select from a datagridview and write a textfile:

`FileInfo arquivo = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\HP8200\Desktop\faturas\" + r.Index + ".txt");`
And I want to change the "r.index" for the variable I showed on the first update

Comment: what kind of a variable are you holding in the TransactionHandler?

Comment: What do you mean by "variable"? Have you tried a public properly? May be you need to read a little about C# and object-oriented programming?

Comment: I'll add some code to the question so it can be easier to answer.

Comment: it is still unclear of what exactly are you trying to do, can u clarify the piece of code or paste the whole class?

Comment: you cannot get to that line of code, if numfatura was a public variable or property yes you probably could but _transaction would need to have been initialized

Comment: I've updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to **use a property instead of a public field**:

```
public class TransactionHandler
{
   private static string numfatura = _transaction.TransDocument + _transaction.TransSerial + _transaction.TransDocNumber;

   public static string Numfatura
   { 
        get { return numfatura ; }
        set { numfatura = value; }
   }
}
```

From another class, you call your variable like this:

```
public class EnviarFaturas
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
         string r.Index= TransactionHandler.Numfatura;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is called 'property' not 'variable'

Comment: Yes,you are right.This is property,Thanks  for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Ok, from what I understand and having no idea of the execution flow you probably need something like this in the TransactionHandler (a property)

```
public int Numfatura
        {
            get
            {
                return this._transaction.TransDocument + this._transaction.TransSerial + this._transaction.TransDocNumber;
            }
        }
```

you can change the type to the one that stands behing the "var" in your code example.

To access it in the form you need an instance of the class (again I dont know what your logic is) but once you get it e.g.

```
var transactionHandler = new TransactionHandler();
```

you can simply try

```
r.Index = transactionHandler.Numfactura;
```

Keep in mind that you can hit the default data value (for int is 0) if your methods depend upon other event to happen.

I strongly suggest you to learn more about C# and Object Oriented Programming as Alexey Zimarev stated in the comments. 
Also you should consider how to get/inject a concrete instance in the view.
Another good and related read will be singleton pattern, mvp and dependency injection.